# Show line number beside Xcode logs

Tags: ios, xcode

How can I configure Xcode to show the number of the line that caused a log to be printed?

I'm seeing logs in my debugger, and I'm not sure where they're coming from.

Answer (score 2):

You can use built in macros: `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__`, `__LINE__`, `__FILE__`, and others.

Objective C example:

```
#define NSLog(__FORMAT__, ...) NSLog((@"%s [Line %d] " __FORMAT__), __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, __LINE__, ##__VA_ARGS__)
```

Swift:

```
println("assertion failed at \(__FILE__):\(__LINE__)")
```

gcc macros: 
https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Standard-Predefined-Macros.html

swift example: https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=15

Comment: This works great for my own logs, but is there a way to enable it for all logs (even from libraries)?

Comment: I think that might be best handled in a separate question, I don't know off hand.